# .htaccess grabbing my css/js

Tags: .htaccess

Due to my htaccess configuration, it seems its grabbing css/js and everything as files.

Here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/?download/(.*)$ download.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ software_cat.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Calling css or javascripts this way

```
<link href="/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

All the files are served by software_cat.php

if i add ad slash like this:

```
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ software_cat.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

all the files work good, BUT nothing points to software_cat.php, so its the same problem but in reverse

How can i fix it so the catchall at the end doesnt work for css/js/images/ etc?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you explain exactly what the issue is? Do you mean everything is served by download.php?

Comment: everything is served by software_cat.php, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your rules lightly like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ /download.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /software_cat.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That way your css, js files will not be forwarded because of `!-d` and `!-f` conditions specified in 2 RewriteCond lines.